# How can I download Java Servlet documentation and attach with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets, javadoc

The question says it all. How can I download java servlet and/or jsp documentation and attach it with Eclipse?

I am using apache tomcat 6.0.32, by the way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you're using Tomcat, you need to download the [Tomcat Source Code Distribution](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi#6.0.32). Here is the [Tomcat 6.0.32 source](http://www.bizdirusa.com/mirrors/apache/tomcat/tomcat-6/v6.0.32/src/apache-tomcat-6.0.32-src.zip). Once downloaded, open a random Servlet API or Tomcat API specific file, e.g. Ctrl+Click or Ctrl+Shift+T `HttpServlet`, then click *Attach source*, then locate the zip file you just downloaded.

That's it.

Answer (score 3):

Download from the Tomcat web page in section **Source Code Distributions** the zip file (not Binary Distributions). Then attach the source to this downloaded file.

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

- Click [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html)
- Search for *Java EE 6 API Update 2 Documentation*, Click download button
- How to add [javadoc in eclipse](https://superuser.com/questions/167458/how-to-add-javadocs-to-eclipse)

Comment: you dont't require downloading it, you can specify the URL in installed JREs properties, it will open if you are on a fast connection, but yeah... dwlding is handy

Comment: then go for [java-ee 5](http://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_Developer-Site/en_US/-/USD/VerifyItem-Start/java_ee_sdk-5_03-javadocs.zip?BundledLineItemUUID=u5.J_hCwQFkAAAEvM7YAGVLN&OrderID=NQCJ_hCwe0sAAAEvJLYAGVLN&ProductID=LknACUFBI3EAAAEYBlw5AXuD&FileName=/java_ee_sdk-5_03-javadocs.zip)

Comment: probably you need to restart/refresh the eclipse